# Visual Studio 2010 useenv option in msbuild doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

When I compile my project using msbuild command with useenv option to include directory I cannot compile my project. It doesn't include the directory in INCLUDE environment variable. My script is as follows,

> cd /d C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin
>
> call vcvars32.bat
>
> SET INCLUDE="C:\Program Files\CA\SCM\HSDK\include";%include%
>
> SET LIB="C:\Program Files\CA\SCM\HSDK\lib";%lib%
>
> cd /d D:\vivilk\H12_Upgrade
>
> echo "Building H12Int"
>
> cd Source\H12Int
>
> msbuild H12Int.sln /p:UseEnv=true;Configuration=Release /t:Clean,Build

This give the error,

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'hsdk.h': No such file or directory

hsdk.h is a file in C:\Program Files\CA\SCM\HSDK\include. So that means it has not identified the include path.

But If I compile this project using Visual Studio 2010 IDE by setting this include and lib directory in Property pages it works. Whats wrong with my build script?

Comment: At last I could solve the issue by removing quotation marks around include directory (C:\Program Files\CA\SCM\HSDK\include).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I could solve the issue by removing quotation marks around include directory (C:\Program Files\CA\SCM\HSDK\include).